# Fsharp.Core 4.4.0.0 and Fable

Tags: f#, fable-f#

Since installing Fable again I am unable to compile anything. The error is:

> internal error: BuildFrameworkTcImports: no resolution of
>   'FSharp.Core, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, Pu
>   blicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a': L1 (startup)

I have no idea how to get Fsharp.Core on my Windows machine luckily with Visual Studio 2013 because it doesn't seem to be on npm even though it's just a dll.

So in "nuget package manager console" I tried:

```
Install-Package FSharp.Core -Version 4.4.0.0
```

It tells me:

> Unable to find version '4.4.0.0' of package 'FSharp.Core'.

So if it's not on npm and not on nuget then where does it come from? All searches lead to nuget but that does not have the version that Fable-compiler requires.

Downloaded it from: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/lib/bootstrap/signed/.NETFramework/v4.0/4.4.0.0/FSharp.Core.dll?raw=true

and referenced it in my fsx:

```
#r "./fsharpcore/4.4.0.0/FSharp.Core.dll"
#r "./node_modules/fable-core/Fable.Core.dll"
open Fable.Core.JsInterop
```

Then try to compile with:

```
node node_modules\fable-compiler\index.js test.fsx .
```

Same error, I will try to copy the dll to some folder so windows can find it

Copied Fsharp.Core.dll to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\.NETFramework\v4.0\4.4.0.0`

Same error though. So checked the package.json and see that fable-compiler 0.0.10 was installed due to an older node that I'm using. Not sure why it workded yesterday but installed node LTS

```
E:\tmp\riot>node --version
v6.9.5
```

Changed the package.json to:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "fable-compiler": "*",
```

Then run `npm install` again

Then copied all the files from https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/tree/master/lib/bootstrap/signed/.NETFramework/v4.0/4.4.0.0 to C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp.NETFramework\v4.0\4.4.0.0

Set the reference in test.fsx to:

```
#r "C:/Program Files (x86)/Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/FSharp/.NETFramework/v4.0/4.4.0.0/FSharp.Core.dll"
#r "./node_modules/fable-core/Fable.Core.dll"
open Fable.Core.JsInterop

Fable.Import.Browser.console.log("Hello World")
```

And compiled with:

```
E:\tmp\riot>node node_modules\fable-compiler\index.js --projFile test.fsx
```

And get error:

> fable-compiler 0.7.42: Start compilation... F# project contains
>   errors: commandLineArgs(L0,0) : error FSHARP: Multiple references to
>   'FSharp.Core.dll' are not permitted commandLineArgs(L0,0) : error
>   FSHARP: Multiple references to 'FSharp.Core.dll' are not permitted

This was because the fableconfig.json pointed to anoher fsx file, removed the reference to FSharp.Core.dll in test.fsx and got it compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several separate issues here:

- FSharp.Core *assembly* versioning is different from *nuget* versioning
- FSharp.Core is an implicit dependency loaded by FSI, so you can't #r reference another version from your script
- fable-compiler requires a working F# installation, it does not ship any of the F# dependencies via npm

TL;DR: you may want to install VS2015 or try this package instead: https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Compiler.Tools/